# Angular Controllers Firing off more than once. Only certain ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have markup that has the following and then I have different sections of the app defined in different files.   The problem I am running into is that the controllers that are on the main app page on load causes each of the nested controllers to run more than once.  Any states that I change to with a click of the button are fine but these fire off 2-3 times each.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<body ng-controller="myController">

<div ng-controller="dashController">

   <div ng-controller="listController">

   </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**My App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'user.profile',
    'myApp.controllers',
    'myApp.directives',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngAutocomplete',
    'ui.router'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.
        state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: '/views/homepage',
            controller: 'MyCtrl1'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

**myApp.controllers**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ui.router','ngCookies']).
  controller('myController', function ($scope, $http,$cookies) {

       $scope.message = 'nothing to see here, move along';
       if ($cookies.userdata) {
           $cookies.userdata = $cookies.userdata.replace("j:", "");
           console.log($cookies);
       }



  });
```

**user.profile.js**

```
angular.module('user.profile', [
        'user.controllers',
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'nouislider',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngLinkedIn'
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$interpolateProvider, $linkedInProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{').endSymbol('}]}');

        $linkedInProvider.set('appKey', '753pos06f998t3')
                         .set('scope', 'r_fullprofile');
                         //.set('authorize', true);

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('userDashboard', {
                controller: 'dashController'
            })
            .state('userList', {
                views : {
                    'popup' : {templateUrl: '/views/app/user/list/userList'}
                },
                controller: 'listController'
            });

    });
```

**user.controllers.js**

```
angular.module('user.controllers', ['ui.router', 'ngAutocomplete', 'nouislider', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'ngLinkedIn', 'angularFileUpload','cgPrompt'])
    .directive('onLastRepeat', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function () {
                scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
            }, 1);
        };
    }).
    controller('dashController', function ($scope, $state, $modal, $log, $http, $cookies) {

      $scope.user = [];

    }).
    controller('listController', function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {

    });
```

My app also doesn't initialize unless I run angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);

I don't think it is having the controller defined in the $stateProvider and the DOM... if I remove from the DOM none of the ng-clicks work even after the controller fires... also I have an ng-click that changes the state and it's controller is defined in the stateProvider and in the DOM and it does not fire twice... what is does is kick off the two other controllers again first before proceeding with it's action though.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are defining your controllers with the routeProvider / stateProvider ie:

```
$stateProvider.state('userDashboard', {
                controller: 'dashController'
            })
            .state('userList', {
                views : {
                    'popup' : {templateUrl: '/views/app/user/list/userList'}
                },
                controller: 'listController'
            });
```

an you are redifining them in the DOM using

```
<div ng-controller="dashController">
```

remove one or the other but don't use the two at the same time, I'd suggest to remove the one declared in the DOM, ng-controller="dashController"

cheers

Comment: I removed the ones in the dom and it still fires more than once

Comment: No I take that back... if I remove the DOM declaration the controller does not fire at all

Comment: If I take out the declaration on the controller, it still fires off 2-3 times